# Using Ratio test to determine convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

In this series I need to use the Ratio test to determine whether the series diverges or converges and I'm not sure about my calculations
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{\pi}{n}\right)^n * n!
$$
plug in n+1 * 1/n

$$
\left( \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}   (n+1)!  * \left( \frac{n}{\pi}\right)^{n} \left( \frac{1}{n!}\right)
$$

$$\left( \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}   (n+1)* \left( \frac{n}{\pi}\right)^{n}$$
$$\left( \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)^{n}   \pi* \left( \frac{n}{\pi}\right)^{n}$$
$$\left( \frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}   \pi$$
$$\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}   \pi = 0$$
which would be 0 so it is convergent ??

Comment: $(n/n+1)^n \ne (1/2)^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n =\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n} =\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\to \frac{1}{e}$$

So the limit of the ratio test should be $\dfrac{\pi}{e}>1$, so your series is divergent.

Comment: ohh Thank you !